# How to check partition type in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have task in which I need to perform installer, who will check the partition type (eg. FAT32, NTFS), and will not allow the installation if the partition does not support file larger than 4GB.

To be honest I have no idea how I can do this. Whether you would have any idea how to go about it? Maybe some piece of code that performs verification of the type of partition?

I would be grateful for any idea to perform this task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an answer for your question [here](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=GetVolumeInformation_%28%29).

This simple example checks the partition type on `wpSelectDir` Page and if `NTFS` is detected on the destination partition it allows to carry on the installation process.

It was written for older version of Inno Setup, so some changes are required (e.g. to `MsgBox`'s `Format2`)
If you are using Unicode Inno you would have to change it a little though.

Below you will find script updated for the latest version of Unicode Inno Setup.

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName=Filesystem
AppVerName=Filesystem
Uninstallable=false
UpdateUninstallLogAppName=false
DisableDirPage=false
DisableProgramGroupPage=true
DefaultDirName={pf}\Filesystem
DisableStartupPrompt=true

[Code]
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif
 
const
  MAX_PATH = 260;

function GetVolumeInformation(lpRootPathName: string; lpVolumeNameBuffer: string;
  nVolumeNameSize: DWORD; out lpVolumeSerialNumber: DWORD;
  out lpMaximumComponentLength: DWORD; out lpFileSystemFlags: DWORD;
  lpFileSystemNameBuffer: string; nFileSystemNameSize: DWORD): BOOL;
  external 'GetVolumeInformation{#AW}@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function NextButtonClick(CurPage: Integer): Boolean;
var srcdisk : String;
    sernum, dummy1, dummy2: DWORD;
    fstype: String;
begin
  Result := true;
  if CurPage = wpSelectDir then
  begin
    srcdisk := AddBackslash(ExtractFileDrive(WizardDirValue));
    fstype := StringOfChar(#0, MAX_PATH + 1);
    if not GetVolumeInformation(
             srcdisk, '', 0, sernum, dummy1, dummy2, fstype, Length(fstype)) then
    begin
      MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(DLLGetLastError), mbError, mb_Ok);
      Result := false;
    end else
    begin
      fstype := Uppercase(Trim(fstype));
      MsgBox (Format('Volume %s has filesystem type (%s)', [
        srcdisk, fstype]), mbInformation, MB_OK);
      // Only carry on if the file system is NTFS.
      Result := (fstype = 'NTFS');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I'm afraid there is no answer to this question. You can get the volume's file system, but you cannot get the maximum size of a file that you can store there (at least I couldn't find a way; searched WMI as well). And since you can use custom file systems, this won't give you a reliable answer (assuming you were having a table with sizes for common file systems).

Comment: FAT32 format allows max file size 4GB. So that method should be enough to check what kind of Volume Format is selected for installation. 
Wiki about [File Allocation Table](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table)

Comment: And custom file systems ? The chance is pretty small but exists. There you are out of luck with all those known file system specifications.

Comment: Custom exception: 'Your file system is not recognized. You may proceed installation on your own risk.' Or limitation that you allow the installation only on NTFS and others you approve/support. You can have modified OS also - then you don't know all of its features...

Comment: Fair enough. Here's a [fixed prototype](http://pastebin.com/wgQj1VZH) (P.S. `GetLastError` may report wrong results because internally used API calls can overwrite the last error code, use built-in `DllGetLastError` instead). And `DWORD` is unsigned type, so `LongInt` is wrong there. And `BOOL` is not `Integer`. Types used by the author look like results of a dice roll (once they used `LongInt`, the other time `Integer` for the same type).

Comment: Thank you RobeN. You are awesome. This is exactly what I needed to know