# I want DefaultDirName to be selected on the hard disk drive with maximum free space

Tags: inno-setup

I am creating an installation using Inno Setup. I want `DefaultDirName` to be selected on the hard disk drive with maximum free space.

Answer (score 2):

Implement a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) to select the disk. Use [`GetDriveType` WinAPI function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypew) to filter to fixed drives (`DRIVE_FIXED`) and [`GetSpaceOnDisk64` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getspaceondisk64) to query the free disk space.

```
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={code:GetDiskWithMostFreeSpace}My Program
```

```pascal
[Code]

const
  DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR = 1;
  DRIVE_FIXED = 3;
  
function GetDriveType(lpRootPathName: string): UInt;
  external 'GetDriveTypeW@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function GetDiskWithMostFreeSpace(Param: string): string;
var
  I: Integer;
  D: string;
  MostFree: Int64;
  Free, Total: Int64;
  T: UInt;
begin
  Result := '';
  MostFree := -1;
  for I := Ord('A') to Ord('Z') do
  begin
    D := Chr(I) + ':\';
    T := GetDriveType(D);
    if T = DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR then
    begin
      Log(Format('Disk %s does not exist', [D]));
    end
      else
    begin
      Log(Format('Disk %s is of type %d', [D, T]));
      if T = DRIVE_FIXED then
      begin
        if not GetSpaceOnDisk64(D, Free, Total) then
        begin
          Log(Format('Cannot obtain free disk space on %s', [D]));
        end
          else
        begin
          Log(Format('Free disk space on %s is %d', [D, Free]));
          if Free > MostFree then
          begin
            MostFree := Free;
            Result := D;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  if Result = '' then
  begin
    RaiseException('Did not find any disk');
  end;

  Log(Format('Selected disk %s', [Result]));
end;
```

The code might be improved with use of `GetVolumeInformation`, as seen in [How to check partition type in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32067591/850848)